# When I use Rdoc to generate HTML, comment blocks are not in the generated html

Tags: rdoc

I am looking at rDoc to comment some code.  I'm not getting
=begin rdoc =end comment blocks to show up in the document.
rdoc 6.0.1 and it generates Darkfish

Comment: Please post a concrete example demonstrating the issue, and how you are building it.

Comment: It looks like the Documentation Can not be at the top of the file.I must be next to a construct module, class, etc.  The test example I built vis >rdoc testFileExample.rb<

Comment: I am having trouble uploading a file...Must be a way other than using comments.

Comment: You can post the code sample inline directly in your question text, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to do that. You cannot attach files, unfortunately.

Comment: =begin rdoc
*Copyright*(c)::
  I would like this block comment in the generated doc
*Filename*:: api-consts.rb
*Author*::   Me
=end

##################
*Copyright*(c)::
  Or this block Comment
*Filename*:: api-consts.rb
*Author*::   Me
##################
require "testInclude.rb"

# It appears that only comments directly before a construct are output
module ApiConsts
 include IncludeModule 
 REST data to set WiFi disabled
 REST_WIFI_DISABLED = {"ap" => { "enabled" => false}, "client" => { "enabled" => false}}
end

Comment: I dont think I got the post correct.  Perhaps my question should be, Is there a way to have a comment block at the begining of a code file in the generated document?

Comment: Feel free to edit the question to better convey what you want to ask